# force logged in user to stay in the dashboard

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-admin, login

I want to force logged-in users to stay in the wp dashboard. If a user logs in and visits a frontend page while being logged in, he should instantly get redirected back to the dashboard. Is there any option to achieve this with a very light weighted solution?

Edited approach thanks to kero and Pat J:

```php
function redirect_back_to_dash(){
    if (is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_redirect(admin_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_back_to_dash');
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: I am not confident if hooking into init is the smartest way

Comment: Probably not, I usually prefer [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook

Comment: Sounds good, Thank You!

Comment: Whatever hook you use, note that, per the docs, [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) should probably be followed by an `exit;` statement.

Comment: You are right, Thank You!